# No persistence.xml file found in project

Tags: jpa, war, ear, persistence.xml

I'm using JBoss Developer Studio 7 (alpha) and have an EAR project with two WARs and one JAR. The JAR is a JPA project. The JAR contains all JPA Entities and also persistance.xml (inside META-INF folder). So I'd like to use the persitence unit defined in the JAR from both WARs. Since the idea is that each WAR has to use the shared persistance.xml from the JAR (JPA project) y removed the persitence.xml in each WAR MATA-INF folder, but then when I want to build the WAR I get "No persistence.xml file found in project (WAR name)".

How I resolve this? If I set some dummy configuration in the WAR persistance.xml the IDE let me buid withot errors, but I don't like this, I have two persitence units that never will be used.

Comment: Would this be similar to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073635/sharing-a-persistence-unit-across-components-in-a-ear-file

Comment: The problem is that the IDE (JBoss Developer Studio 7) is requiring on build time that in each WAR has to found persintance.xml in the WAR META-INF folder.

Comment: Have you tried adding the folder with the persistence.xml to your WAR projects classpath