# Persistence Unit fails to inject first time an app is published but succeeds when app is restarted

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, websphere

When i first start up my application server with the already published deployed app, any attempt to inject the persistence unit declared in a particular module fails the first time the bean declaring it is invoked. I can solve the issue by restarting the application, however this consistently happens every time I republish.

I am using WebSphere v8.0.4.2 and developing through Rational Application Developer v8 (although I think that's irrelevant).

**NOTE:** the `ABCBean` contains the `EntityManager` and resides in the `ABC.jar`, and The `OTHERMODULE.jar` is the code that the exception relates to. the modules are a part of one EAR file.

so:

```
ABC
\__ ABCBean
\__ META-INF/persistence.xml

OTHERMODULE
\__ beans that call above bean and cannot resolve persistence unit.
```

The exception I get when invoking my persistence bean is:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The ABCBean/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the ABCBean component in the XYZ.jar module of the MYAPP application cannot be resolved.
javax.ejb.EJBException: The ABCBean/em reference of type javax.persistence.EntityManager for the ABCBean component in the OTHERMODULE.jar module of the MYAPP application cannot be resolved.
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectionObject(InjectionBinding.java:1100)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionBinding.getInjectableObject(InjectionBinding.java:1013)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionTarget.inject(InjectionTarget.java:198)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.inject(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:947)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.StatelessBeanO.initialize(StatelessBeanO.java:300)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanOFactory.create(BeanOFactory.java:147)...
```

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" ...>
    <persistence-unit name="ABC_EJB">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/***</jta-data-source>
        ...
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the Class in the exception:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ABCBean {
    ...

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ABC_EJB")
    private EntityManager em;
    ...

}
```

Comment: why don't you use just one bean file ? just saying...

Comment: please ellaborate. the domain of our app is contained within one jar and is depended on by the rest of the application. the OTHERMODULE stands as a global controller of the other jars in order to be able to invoke code from across the application.

Comment: I think this might solve you issue. In beans.xml, you have to add <context:component-scan base-package="otherModule.xyz.dao" /> and in Persistence.xml, you have to add <jar-file>WEB-INF/lib/otherModule.jar</jar-file>... Hope this might solve your issue.

Comment: Why do i need a beans.xml file? i thought that was a jsf managed bean specific config. the bean i have is an EJB.

Comment: I am not sure how you do it in jsf, as i did the something similar which i explained when i got the similar kind of error wicket application.

Comment: beans.xml should not be neededif this is a pure JavaEE application.  Can you search the SystemOut.log for other errors (Caused By for the EJBException, or CWWJPxxxxE message before the exception stack trace) that gives a hint?  In any case, the non-determinism sounds like it might be a product defect.

Comment: As far as i can see, the EJBException is the root cause of the problem. is the problem that i need to have the persistence.xml jar inside the lib folder of the EAR maybe? am i expecting too much from calling the beans with the entity manager from another module. i would think that the encapsulation of the bean and the entity manager in the ABC.jar would stop this from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The persistence context is not referencable to the `OTHERMODULE`  because the it is limited to the scope of the ABC.jar. the answer with the most votes at the bottom of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073635/sharing-a-persistence-unit-across-components-in-a-ear-file) shows the documentation related to sharing persistence.xml contexts across an EAR deployment. here is an excerpt from the specs:

> the root of a persistence unit must be one of the following:
>
> - an EJB-JAR file
> - the WEB-INF/classes directory of a WAR file[80]
> - a jar file in the WEB-INF/lib directory of a WAR file
> - **a jar file in the EAR library directory**
> - an application client jar file

AND

> A persistence unit that is defined at the level of the EAR is generally visible to all components in the application. However, if a persistence unit of the same name is defined by an EJB-JAR, WAR, or application jar file within the EAR, the persistence unit of that name defined at EAR level will not be visible to the components defined by that EJB-JAR, WAR, or application jar file unless the persistence unit reference uses the persistence unit name # syntax to specify a path name to disambiguate the reference.

my solved project structure is as follows:

```
APP_EAR
\__lib
    \__domain.jar
        \__META-INF
            \__persistence.xml (with <jar-file>../ABC.jar</jar-file> element because ABC module contains entity classes).
\__ABC.jar
\__OTHERMODULE.jar
```

afterwards i could remove all the ejb-jar persistence-context-refs from the file and it would still resolve the reference.